# No WiFi networks listed; Ubuntu 20.04; Broadcom BCM4360

Tags: wireless, 20.04, broadcom

I'm not able to view any wifi networks using my BCM4360 network card in my laptop using 20.04. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks.

Please let me know if any other information is required to help debug this problem

Edit: Interestingly, ubuntu is able to list nearby bluetooth devices.

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network


03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0112]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

```
dmesg | grep wl


[    4.145754] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.145759] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    4.152672] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.246755] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    4.592163] wl 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
rfkill list all


0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Some others have experienced same issue, solved by reinstalling the module : `sudo apt-get remove --purge  bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt-get -y install  bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; Nothing changed after reinstalling the module. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Install the wireless driver
Run the following commands in the terminal to install the driver:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

After the installation is complete, restart your computer and check if the wireless adapter is working.

Try loading the driver module manually
If the above steps do not work, try manually loading the driver module using the following command:

sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma

sudo modprobe wl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In Jan 2021 my network stopped on a MacBook Air 2015 after an Ubuntu 20.04 update.

This a summary of how I got it working again:

```
Enable the use of proprietary drivers. For example in 'Software & Updates / Ubuntu Software'
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove --purge  bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install --reinstall broadcom-sta-dkms
Reboot you computer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this driver:
https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl/tree/patch-linux4.7

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

# wireless drivers (conflict with Broadcom hybrid wireless driver 'wl')
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcma
blacklist b43
blacklist brcmsmac
```

Build and install for the running kernel:

```
$ make
$ make install
$ depmod -A
$ modprobe wl
```

Answer (score 0):

during August 2021 kernel 5.11.0-25-generic update , the broadcom wifi stopped working

The purge and reinstall got it working again.

BR